# Print the values of nested hash corresponding to key

Tags: ruby

I have a nested hash,

```
@metals = {
  "1" => {"Aluminum" => 100}, 
  "2" => {"Steel" => 80}, 
  "3" => {"Copper" => 60}
}
```

and I am trying to extract the keys and values from it. When a user submits `1`, I want to print both `Aluminum` and `100`.

My code is:

```
puts "Which metal do you want to use?"
@metals.each do |key1, value1|
  value1.each do |key2, value2|
    puts "Select #{key1} for #{key2}"
  end
end
@metalsdata = gets.chomp
if @metals.has_key?(@metalsdata)
  puts "#{@metalsdata}"
else
  puts "Invalid option"
end
```

I iterated the hash to display the option to the user.

Comment: Replace `"#{@metalsdata}"` by `"#{@metals[@metalsdata].inspect}"`

Comment: `@metals[@metalsdata]`, or break it out by key/value. That said, this smells of an actual class rather than a simple map.

Comment: @sschmeck It will print a hash but i don't want it. I want both key and value in a separate variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `puts "#{@metalsdata}"` you could write:

```
key, value = @metals[@metalsdata].first
```